# How best to specify an interface subclass to use based on configuration

Tags: python, interface, overriding

I would like to create a single "interface" class (in interface.py) through which I can access an underlying class's functionality, where the class accessed is dependent on a xml config_file setting. 
Taking connection via ssh, or ftp as an example.

I'd have a variable set in my config file such as
`"INTERFACE": "ssh"`

Then I'd expect to have code that looks something like this:

```
# file = interface.py
class Interface(?)
    def connect(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self

# file = ssh.py
class SSH(?)
    def connect(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Setup a connection
        connection = paramiko.SSHClient()
        return connection

#file = ftp.py
class FTP(?)
    def connect(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Setup a connection
        return connection

# And in my calling code I would just like a generic call e.g.
from path.interface import Interface

foo = Interface()
foo.connect(bar)    # Where "INTERFACE" : "ssh"
```

Then the `SSH` class would (override?) execute its code defined in its version of `connect()`.
If I then change the config setting to config.INTERFACE = "ftp", the same call would "find its way" to the ftp class to establish an ftp connection.

Ideally I'd be able to flip between the different version of `connect()` with my code, simply by setting:

```
config.INTERFACE = "ssh"
config.INTERFACE = "ftp"
```

I assume this isn't some unachievable thing? I don't even know what to google to find out how to do this! Is this overriding?
Any advice would be gratefully received. 
Just a topic to google would be a starting point. :)

Comment: ssh and ftp are just examples not what I'm trying to code.
It's the structure I'm trying to learn. The override or inheritance or ?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the utility here... What's the significant difference between doing `config.INTERFACE = "ssh"` and `config = SSH()`?  It doesn't seem like having the interface does very much for you.

Comment: "INTERFACE" : "ssh"
Would be one of many lines in an XML config file. 
The contents of which would end up in config.
So to access the value for INTERFACE would be config.INTERFACE

Comment: Ok ... It still seems like you should just use the value of `config.INTERFACE` to pick the proper class (`SSH` or `FTP`).

Comment: How to do that is my question?

Answer (score 1):

A standard pattern of doing this is something like this:

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta

class Interface(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def upload(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('Must implement upload in subclasses')

class SSH(Interface):

    def upload(self):
        # ssh implementation

class FTP(Interface):

    def upload(self):
        # ftp implementation

def InterfaceForConfigurationValue(interface_value):
    if interface_value == 'ssh':
        return SSH()

    if interface_value == 'ftp':
        return FTP()

    raise NotImplementedError('Interface not available for value %s' % (
        interface_value,))
```

- `Interface` is the abstract base class defining the interface you want to use. Useless on its own, it needs concrete subclasses to implement it.

  Note that for this to be a useful abstraction and worth the effort, you want to make this more tailored to you applications and provide higher level APIs, such as `upload()` or `get()`, or else it's a bit pointless, and you may find it's hard to generalize to different protocols.
- `SSH` and `FTP` both override the `upload()` method of their superclass (`Interface`) and so you can call `upload()` on your `Interface` instance without worrying about which particular subclass it is.
- `InterfaceForConfigurationValue` is a factory function that gives you the correct interface subclass based on the configuration option.

In general the most important thing is to ensure that nothing about `Interface`, `SSH` or `FTP` knows or cares what is in the config file, because you may wish to use them elsewhere with a different config system. They just know what they need to do. You add a factory function which is small and contains the knowledge of how to translate your config into a subclass.

Note: your factory function doesn't have to be a global function. Often you'll find there are lots of similar bits of linking you need to do between your config system and your code, so you may want to use a class and have the factory as a method on the class. A subclass of [`ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser) is often a good option.

Comment: Apologies for not coming back to this. The priority for me to do this dropped off a cliff and is slowly climbing back up again!
I've not had chance to try the above but it look pretty convincing. :) 
Thank you for your time/help all.